# How to use Global Variable in a function and then use the output of the function in another function

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to initialize a global variable and then use it in a function to compute the number of clicks and then use the computed output in another function inside a for loop to set the max limit i.e. `for(i=0; i >= count; i++)`. The issue I'm having here is that since the variable is global, I'm unable to use the computed value of the onClick function in my submitForm() function. The value to the variable 'count' get reassigned to 0 as it is global.

```
let count=0;

var add=document.querySelector('.fa-plus'); 
add.addEventListener('click', () =>{
       //Product Label
       count=count+1;
}

//to check if the variable has the computed result 
console.log(count);

function submitForm(e){
   for(i=0; i <= count; i++){
  const prod[i] = document.querySelector('#prod-'+i).value;
  ipcRenderer.send('item:add', item);                
   }
}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I had created a variable outside the onclick() function so that everytime the user clicks on the button the counter variable is incremented by 1, also I wanted to use this variable in another function to set the limit in the for loop

Comment: You still haven't asked a question, only stated some requirements. You want to use a global variable in multiple places -- so do it; what's stopping you? What is the specific problem you have? Take a look at [ask].

Comment: The question here is, I have initialized the variable outside the functions and then used the variable in the onClick function so that it computes the results. But in this case when I call the variable doesn't store the computed value instead stores a '0' which was assigned to the variable during declaration. So, I want to store the value in variable and then use the computed value in another function.

Comment: It sounds like you are saying that `count` inside the `submitForm` function is always `0` even after the click event handler should have updated it. Unfortunately, you don't have a [mcve] so it is impossible to reproduce the issue or even guess at what is happening because we can't see the full structure and how the functions are being called.

Comment: My guess: the count that you're updating with this:

`add.addEventListener('click', () =>{
       //Product Label
       count=count+1;
}`

Isn't the global count, but a localized one. So it's not that your count is getting reset to 0, or that it's being reset because it's global... it's never being updated in the first place. I'd be willing to bet that if you changed your `let count =0;` to another variable name, and left all of the counts as they are... it would still work the same and you'd see the same thing you are now.

Comment: No no, If I don't initialize it to zero globally the click count doesn't work. If I declare the variable inside the function and initialize it to zero then every time the function is called the variable value starts with zero. And it is something that I do not want.

Answer (score -1):

```
add.addEventListener('click', function(){
   //+= is just a shortcut. You can also use count++
   count+=1;
});
```

You’re also probably better off using var instead of let since trying to change a let usually results in a syntax error.

Based off of https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp

(Also, unless you want the for loop to loop count+1, have it be i < count. Remember i starts at 0, not 1.)

Comment: `let` should always be preferred over `var`. The only time you would get a syntax error when trying to change the value as you stated, would be if you had a duplicate `let variable_name` in the same scope, which is bad code.

Comment: Also, this doesn't provide any sort of answer. You just rearranged the `add.addEventListener(...` that was in the original question, but it does exactly the same thing.\

Comment: Buddy, I am looking for a solution and not for shortcuts.